# Is there a program like Ubuntu's "System Testing" tool for other Linux distros?

Tags: linux, compatibility

Ubuntu has a program called "System Testing" which prompts the user to test various elements of their system (sound through headphones, sound through system speakers, network connectivity, available monitor resolutions, etc), then reports this information to Canonical's Ubuntu Friendly page.

- Are there similar tools available for other distros?
- Is there a portable app which can test across multple distros?
- Are there test suites which go beyond Ubuntu's System Testing tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, I've found [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/), which contains a series of compatibility tests. The test suite is widely portable; there is also a live distro which contains the test suite. All results are sent to http://openbenchmarking.org/.